# what could be used hanging object such as painting on wall without nails?

Tags: adhesives, material-selection

Is there any adhesive material through which we can hang painting and photo frames on wall without nails.Such that on removing it not damage the walls?

Comment: important information is missing in your question. Do you require that the frames be removable without damage to the wall or painted surface? How much weight is involved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the questions in my comment, one answer to your question may be to use 3M Command Adhesive products. These are double sided foam strips with an accessory attached to one side. Sometimes the accessory is a hook made from formed/molded plastic, sometimes it's a metal hook on a strap-like attachment.

Other versions use a velcro-type product on the foam adhesive strip. You attach one piece of the velcro to your frame and the other (foam) velcro to the wall with the 3M adhesive.

Many other accessories exist and most are available in local retail outlets as well as on Amazon.com

The key feature of this product is that when it is necessary to remove the hanging item, one pulls on the tab attached to the foam tape. It stretches and distorts and releases in a controlled manner, creating nearly zero damage to the underlying surface. I say nearly zero, because poorly painted surfaces may crack and peel, but properly painted surfaces will release cleanly.

There are versions of this product that are rated by the weight each strip will hold safely. If you have a 10 kg frame and can find only 5 kg capable strips, get two, and you'll be safe.

Comment: +1 for Velcro, I’ve used it before and it’s an awesome approach.

Comment: Maybe add "If pulled in the right direction" before "It stretches". :D

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is an arrow on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Galleries, museums and some home owners use picture rails - strips mounted on the top of walls. The pictures get hung on wires (for heavier objects) or transparent / wall colored strings that hook onto the rails.

The traditional version is often wider, and a decorative element per se (aka picture molding), but there are thin and unobtrusive models for a modern sleek look available. Find examples of different styles and more details [here](https://www.picturehangingsystems.com/picture-rail-hanging-system) (random example, not an endorsement).

The main advantage is that there is no damage to the walls (unless you count the area where the picture rails are mounted, but they are typically considered a permanent item) and pictures can be rearranged or exchanged easily.